# Reference on same slide in beamer and with \pause

Tags: latex, beamer, biblatex

I have been searching for some automated way of numbering the references on the same slide in beamer Madrid with biblatex. This works fine with `\pause` and `\footcite{}`. But when I have multiple bullets on the same slide (e.g. 5), and I want to cite for the last point, the problem is that the reference appears from the very first slide. I want that the reference appears only when the relevant slide appears (i.e. 5th one in this case)

- `\documentclass{beamer}`
- `\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}`
- `\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}`

`\only<2->{...}` etc. is one solution but I think it is a lot of manual work to update all numbers on the slide when, for instance, I need to remove (or add) one point with a reference.

Thanks.

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre] instead of posting only fragments of code that a user has to first puzzle together before even starting to work on a solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to update any numbers if you use relative overlays instead of absolute numbers:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item ABC \only<.->{\footcite{knuth:ct:a}}
            \item XYZ \only<.->{\footcite{knuth:ct:b}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey you surely have the answer to my question for which i m going crazy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654205/latex-beamer-how-to-make-footcites-appear-sequentially